# WPF make element's top position fixed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML in my WPF application:

```
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.524,0.496" Height="478" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,22,0,0" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" Background="AliceBlue" Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Label x:Name="label" Content="Science Magazine - Papers" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="6" FontSize="16" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
```

I wanted the canvas to be resizable with the window, which I achieved by binding its width with the width of the window. However, I also want it to stay at the same top position when the window is resized; instead, it does this:[image]

I don't know how to fix this (since I'm a complete WPF beginner :) )

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `Grid` `VerticalAlignment="Top"` instead of `Bottom`

Answer (score 0):

You can place your `Grid` inside a `DockPanel` and set the `Dock` property to `Top`. You can also specify some margins from the `DockPanel`.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: That didn't work, the canvas is still being moved down when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Try making two rows, first one with auto height, in witch goes your canvas, and the second one for the rest of content of page. That way first row (canvas) will take up only needed space at the top of the page, and the second row will take up all remaining space.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
        <!--content of canvas-->
    </Canvas>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!--rest of the content-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think a StackPanel is a much simpler choice:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,50,0,0" Background="Red" Height="43" >
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Science Magazine - Papers" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="6" FontSize="16" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Note that there is no need for Binding the width or using horizontal or vertical Alignments